# Tough Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable of invoices, these invoices have line items. These line items have a priority.  I'm programming a variety of strategies to automatically apply cash against these line items and one is giving me some trouble. My pattern has been to prepare a linq statement to order the line items of the invoices then iterate over the linq query applying cash in order until I run out.

An example of this linq statement for the simplest strategy, pay each line item by priority and due date, is shown below:

```
from lineItem in invoices.SelectMany(invoice => invoice.LineItems)
orderby lineItem.Priority, lineItem.DueDate
select lineItem;
```

One of the strategies is to apply cash to the oldest remaining item with a given priority, in priority order, then move to the next oldest of each priority.

EDIT: Example of how one might start the query I'm asking for -

```
from lineItem in invoices.SelectMany(invoice => invoice.LineItems)
group lineItem by lineItem.Priority into priorities
orderby priorities.Key
select priorities.OrderBy(item => item.DueDate);
```

We now have "buckets" of line items with the same priority, ordered by due date within the bucket. I need to extract the first line item from each bucket, followed by the second, etc. until I have ordered all of the items. I would like to perform this ordering purely in linq.

Can anyone think of a way to express this entirely in linq?

Comment: You just did! What are you asking that your query doesn’t already do?

Comment: @Timwi - I think the example shows a simplified strategy - the actual required strategy is summed up in a single paragraph below the code. @marr75 it would be really helpful if you could give us a concrete example - such as some example `LineItems` and the order that they should be bought in using the new strategy.

Comment: The first query does exactly what the paragraph states is required. The second query (after the “Edit”) does some fancy grouping which does not appear to be necessary.

Comment: @Timwi for the simpler strategy, yes, the first example does exactly as required. I've come to the conclusion that to do what I need I'll have to mimic row_order (a ranking within the group) within the buckets I've made in the grouping, I will then sort by this ranking then by priority. Can anyone think of a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Timwi - I don't *think* it does. It reads to me like - pay for the oldest item in priority 1, then the oldest item in priority 2, then the oldest item in priority 3, then the next oldest item in priority 1 etc. That's not the same as the first example. However, I'm not sure even that's correct which is why I asked for a concrete example.

Comment: @Alex Humphrey nailed it. Like I said, it is a subtle difference, but a difference that makes the query much more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how you'll get this down to a better query than what you have, perhaps nest `from` queries to automatically do the `SelectMany`.

```
var proposedPayments = new List<LineItem>();
decimal cashOnHand = ...;
var query = invoices.SelectMany(iv => iv.LineItems)
                    .GroupBy(li => li.Priority)
                    .SelectMany(gg =>
                         gg.OrderBy(li => li.DueDate)
                           .Select((li,idx) => Tuple.Create(idx, gg.Key, li)))
                    .OrderBy(tt => tt.Item1)
                    .ThenBy(tt => tt.Item2)
                    .Select(tt => tt.Item3);
foreach (var item in query)
{
    if (cashOnHand >= item.Cost)
    {
        proposedPayments.Add(item); 
        cashOnHand -= item.Cost;
    }

    if (cashOnHand == 0m) break;
}
```

**Edit:** updated to match the paragraph the author wanted. Selected as first of each priority.

Comment: Agreed, the example query I gave was fine, I may not have been clear, I need a query to express the order I was talking about in the paragraph after it.

Comment: Yep, this is about what I ended up with. I didn't use a tuple, but an anonymous type instead (calling a property Rank adds to readability). Thank you StackOverflow for staying with me on this.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ = Language Integrated QUERY not Language Integrated PROCEDURAL CODE.

If you want a query that returns the line items you need to apply the payment to, then that's do-able (see `.Aggregate`), but if you want to actually apply the money to the line items as you go, then a `foreach` loop is a fine construct to use.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know, I am fine applying a foreach loop after I have ordered the line items, this way the side effects are explicit. What I'm looking for is a way to express the ordering of the second strategy I discussed.

Comment: @marr75: What's the difference between the "second strategy" and the one you've already coded? It looks to me like your existing query should work...

Comment: It's a subtle difference, let me know if the added example helps make the distinction clear.